# Multiple Join not working on two string attributes

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have the following issue:

I have several tables in my Database, in order to check for a specific criteria I have to join several tables, where I use the following statement:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT * FROM (((((((((SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE tab1_id = 1)  AS A
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE tab2_variable IS NOT NULL) AS B
                ON A.variable = B.variable)
            INNER JOIN (SELECT table3.*, IIF(year='XXXX', 0, 1) AS flag FROM table3) AS C
                ON A.h_name = C.h_name)
            INNER JOIN (SELECT * FROM table4 WHERE s_flag = 0) AS D
                ON C.v_type = D.v_type)
            INNER JOIN table5
                ON C.ng_type = table5.ng_type)
            INNER JOIN table6
                ON C.part = table6.part)
            INNER JOIN table7
                ON C.ifg = table7.ifg)
            INNER JOIN table8
                ON C.v_type = table8.v_type AND C.ng_typ = table8.ng_typ AND C.ntr_flag = table8.ntr_flag)
            INNER JOIN table9
                ON table8.ifg_sii_id = table9.ifg_sii_id)) AS F
        LEFT JOIN table10
            ON F.risk = table10.risk AND C.v_type = table10.v_type
                AND F.series = table10.series
```

This statement fails. But when I remove one the following two join-conditions in the last `Left JOIN`, it works as intended:

`F.risk = table10.risk` and/or `C.v_type = table10.v_type`

They are both of type `CHAR`, whereas series is type `TINYINT`, I guess it has something to do with joining on multiple conditions with strings, but I'm not able to find a workaround, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to your current SQL, Table `C` is not visible as it's a sub query within `F`. instead of `C.v_type` you need to use `F.c_v_type` and the `c_v_type` field must come from `C` table like. `select v_type as c_v_type from table3... as C`

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

In the last part of your Query You could try to actually select the table and include the Where Clause Like so:

```
LEFT JOIN (Select * from table10 Where C.v_type = v_type AND F.series = series) as xx
        ON F.risk = xx.risk
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, when I try this I get prompted to enter the Parametervalue of `C.v_type`.